# SQL select only first with a given name

Tags: sql

Houses

```
id OwnerId    street
-----------------------
1  owner1     street1
2  owner2     street1
3  owner3     street2
4  owner4     street2
5  owner5     street3
```

As you can see there can be more owners on the same street

I have another table where I want to insert the owners from `Houses` table, but only one from each street

Result of query:

table StreetRepresentant

```
ownerId    street 
------------------
owner1     street1
owner3     street2
owner5     street3
```

(`ownerId` is the PK for the table, if it matters. `OwnerId` is a unique in table `Houses`)

The query should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO StreetRepresentant (ownerId , street ) 
SELECT ownerId , street 
FROM Houses
--what should be here to get only 1 owner for each street? ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by street, then use the `MIN()` function to return the lowest (as per your example) ownerId for each street.

```
SELECT MIN(ownerId) , street 
FROM Houses
GROUP BY street
```

Comment: ownerID is not int. It is varchar what aggregate function can I use instead of min?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO StreetRepresentant (ownerId , street ) 
SELECT ownerId , street 
FROM Houses h
GROUP BY h.street, h.ownerId
```

Comment: Grouping by both? OP wants only 1 owner per street.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: The `GROUP BY` should be compatible with `SELECT` else you will get an error.

Comment: Your query will return 3 rows for street1, since there are 3 different owners. Please read the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at something like

```
SELECT  Street,
        MIN(ID) FirstAvailableID
FROM    Houses
GROUP BY    Street
```

Answer (score 0):

use Distinct keyword while selecting the rows, hope it will work.

Comment: `DISTINCT` check the **rows**, and there are no duplicate rows.